# Get field names from a TFRecord

Tags: tensorflow

Given a .tfrecord file, we can define a record iterator

`record_iterator = tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(path=record)`

Then parse it using

`example = tf.train.SequenceExample()
for element in record_iterator:
    example.ParseFromString(element)`

The question is: how do we infer all the field names in the context ?
If we know the structure in advance, we can say `example.context.feature["width"]`. In addition, `str(example.context)` returns a string with the entire record structure. However, I was wondering if there is any built-in function to get the field names and avoid parsing this string (e.g. by searching for `"key"`)